# SQL select count of all rows when using IF ELSE

Tags: sql, count, sql-server-2008-r2, if-statement

I have a situation when I use IF ELSE statement in SQL.

```
    @searchString nvarchar(50),
    @languageId int, 
    @count int,
    @id int
IF(@count IS NOT NULL)
    SELECT TOP (@count) Id, value
    FROM TABLE1
        WHERE  (Id IN
        (SELECT Id
    FROM      TABLE2
    WHERE   (Id = @id))) and languageId = @languageId AND value LIKE '%' + @searchString + '%'
ORDER BY value

ELSE
    SELECT Id, value
    FROM TABLE1
        WHERE  (Id IN
        (SELECT Id
        FROM      TABLE2
    WHERE   (Id = @id))) and languageId = @languageId AND value LIKE '%' + @searchString + '%'
ORDER BY value
```

I would like to return number of all rows using 
            count(*) over() (or something similar) 
(as I return only TOP count records for now), like it is answered here:
[How to return total number of records with TOP * select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637254/how-to-return-total-number-of-records-with-top-select)

BUT: I wouldn't return this value for every instance, but I would like to return count just once.

Is there a way to do this with one query, or I have to write a separate query for this?

Any hint would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: using SQL server 2008 r2.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to mention: SQL server 2008 r2

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use INNER JOIN, for Exemple with scripts:
{
SCRIPT

SELECT

```
                l.localite_id,
                p.patient_id,
                p.patient_date_naissance, 
                p.patient_gsm, p.patient_tel
```

FROM
                    patient p
INNER JOIN   localite l
ON                  l.localite_id = p.localite_id
INNER JOIN   ville v
ON                  v.ville_id = l.ville_id
INNER JOIN   gouvernorat g
ON                  v.gouv_id = g.gouv_id
INNER JOIN   pays pays
ON                  pays.pays_id = g.pays_id

IF NEQ #patient_gsm# -1
WHERE  p.patient_gsm like #patient_gsm#

AND p.patient_code like #patient_code#

ENDIF

END

}