# Angular 8 Http multiple calls or streaming

Tags: angular, angular8

im using Angular8, my problem is: i have a table which sends a request to my server to get the records, at the moment the server just "SELECT * from TABLE" and return the whole data at once.

problem is now that "TABLE" is very big and it takes time to load the table.

i want to make a first call to the server and "SELECT * from TABLE limit 1000"
and then execute another call and load the rest of the data.
but i can't find how its possible to return only one observable and "stream" the results..

the table component looks like this:

```
this.apiService.loadTable().subscribe(data => { this.source.load(data) })
```

(where this.source.load is a function of ngx-smart-table)

i want that the loadTable function will update the data when one of the request finishes..
how can i accomplish that?
i didn't find how i can take different http requests and emit their results on a single observable object..

thanks!

Comment: I would recommend implementing pagination or a virtual scroll (infinite scroll) if you want show entire data in a single page.

Comment: Also you might be interested in [web scokets](https://blog.angulartraining.com/how-to-use-websockets-with-rxjs-and-angular-b98e7fd8be82)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pushing all records to the client is often a bad idea. It is best you tie it to some user action that indicates the user wants more records e.g. clicking on a "more" button, scrolling to the bottom of the table etc.

But if you must, you can always "re-subscribe" in the previous subscription. In the code below, loadData calls itself if there is more record from the server:

```
...
loadData (pageNumber = 1, pageSize = 20) {
    this.apiService.loadTable(pageNumber, pageSize).subscribe(response => {
        this.source.load(response.data);
        if (pageNumber < response.totalPageCount) {
             loadData(pageNumber++, pageSize);
        }
    })
}
...
```

ngx-smart-table already includes pagination, so I recommend you stick to that.

Someone else also suggested using websockets, but that comes with its own set of cons and pros.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you do those kind of things with some pagination logic. 
That could work for example like this:

```
this.apiService.loadTable(pageNumber, pageSize).subscribe(data => { this.source.load(data) })

// pageNumber is the actual number (initially 1)
// pageSize defines the amount of datasets you want to load.
```

Then, in your service and in your backend you have to implement that logic as well to only retrieve certain data.

For the SQL implementation you might want to have a look here: 
[SQL Server query with pagination and count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21537511/sql-server-query-with-pagination-and-count)

Hope that helps.

Comment: how the search works with pagination? if data is not loaded so the table filter won't work properly