# Get count from SQL query with offset

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to get the total count in SQL query?

Below is my SQL query where to display count

```
DECLARE @rowPerPage INT = 30, 
@pageNumber INT = 1 

SELECT 
  a.*, 
  string_agg(a.firstname, ',') AS user_first_name, 
  string_agg(a.lastname, ',') AS user_last_name 
FROM 
  (
    a.user AS user, 
    a.userage AS age, 
    a.useraddress AS address 
    FROM 
      userinfo user 
      LEFT JOIN address 
    ADD 
      ON user.id = 
    ADD 
      .userid 
      LEFT JOIN roll ON 
    ADD 
      .id = roll.userid
  ) AS a 
GROUP BY 
  a.id a.sub a.roller 
ORDER BY 
  (
    SELECT 
      0
  ) OFFSET (@pageNumber -1) * @rowPerPage ROWS FETCH next @rowPerPage ROWS only
```

Desired output SQL Server database.

It should also display total count item, I am not sure how to achieve this.

Can anyone help to resolve this.

Thank you

Comment: If SQL server `count(*) over ()`?

Comment: it is SQL Server where should I put count(*) over () ?

Comment: I did put count(*) over () after a.useraddress AS address  but it does say no column name was specified for column. of a I guess nearby groupby there is a issue

Comment: That is error is telling you to alias the column I.e. give it a name.

Comment: But yeah group by is going to cause an issue, you might need a further sub-query

Comment: can you please help to make this ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21537511/sql-server-query-with-pagination-and-count#21537760

Comment: And `order by (select 0)` - what is the point of that?

Comment: if I would be putting field name it keep sending for long time I google it and found this

Comment: can you please help to write psudo code for this ?

Comment: The link I posted above shows you the pseudo code. Please have a try and report back when you are stuck.

Comment: Your order by clause is fast because it's not ordering i.e. it simply isn't working, if you don't correctly order then your paging fails.

Comment: You need to understand conceptually what you are trying to do, cobbling together SQL from here and then isn't going to work.

Comment: okay one more thing if I put @pageNumber INT = 2000 it is taking more than 5 mins any reason ?

Comment: Yeah you have a large table without the correct indexes.

Comment: And what database are you actually using? Because that is not SQL server syntax

Comment: You should consider not paging by rownumber at all. Instead use Keyset Pagination, admittedly you can't find the total number of rows in this way. But it's much much faster.