# SQL Query to select certain number of records with WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have a table that looks like the following:

```
ID | EntityType | Foo  | Bar
----------------------------
1  | Business   | test | test
2  | Family     | welp | testing
3  | Individual | hmm  | 100
4  | Family     | test | test
5  | Business   | welp | testing
6  | Individual | hmm  | 100
```

This table is fairly large, and there are random (fairly infrequent) instances of "Business" in the EntityType column.

A query like

```
SELECT TOP 500 * FROM Records WHERE EntityType='Business' ORDER BY ID DESC
```

works perfectly for grabbing the first set of Businesses, now how would I page backwards and get the previous set of 500 records which meet my criteria?

I understand I could look at records between IDs, but there is no guarantee on what ID that would be, for example it wouldn't just be the last ID of the previous query minus 500 because the Business EntityType is so infrequent.

I've also looked at some paging models but I'm not sure how I can integrate them while keeping my WHERE clause just how it is (only accepting EntityType of Business) and guaranteeing 500 records (I've used one that "pages" back 500 records, and only shows about 18 businesses because they're within the 500 total records returned).

I appreciate any help on this matter!

Comment: Is there a reason this link won't work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790965/return-total-records-from-sql-server-when-using-row-number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from ( 
  select top 500 * from (
    select top 1000 * FROM Records WHERE EntityType='Business' ORDER BY ID DESC 
  ) x
  order by id 
) y 
order by id desc
```

Innermost query - take the top 1000, to get page 2 and page 1 results

2nd level query - take the page 2 records from the first query

outermost - reorder the results

Comment: Seems fairly inefficient.  Fairly certain ROWCOUNT leads to better performance if not a more readable query.

Comment: @DylanB - please tell me why this would be inefficient and how rowcount would be better ?

Comment: I might be wrong, but I would expect a rowcount to do the ordering more efficiently, without a full select of the thousand rows.  The compiler might clean this up and make the two queries operationally equivalent.  NOTE: This solution also has the disadvantage of only working for 1-2 pages of data, where one based on rowcounts would work for N pages.  I never finished writing a workable solution, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you need is called paging. There is great article on paging on CodeGuru (I think it was mentioned here before):

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_data/article.php/c19611/Paging-in-SQL-Server-2005.htm

I think there you will find everything you need

Answer (score 1):

So, I'd do this slightly differently from the other answers.  My query to always pull the 500 last rows with a minimum row would look like this and require a rowcount.

Note that using a rowcount outside the query makes it exponentially easier to push through SQL syntax.  I wish it wasn't necessary.

```
Declare @row_min as integer
Declare @row_count as integer
set @row_min = 500
SELECT @row_count = COUNT(*) FROM Records WHERE EntityType='Business' ;
WITH MyCTE AS 
(
    SELECT 
    ID, EntityType, Foo, Bar,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TagId) AS 'RowNum'
       FROM Records
       WHERE EntityType='Business'
)

Select TOP 500 *, (Select Max(RowNum) From MyCTE) As RowMax
FROM MyCTE
WHERE EntityType='Business'
    AND
    RowNum > 
        Case sign(@row_count - 500 - @row_min)
        When -1 Then (@row_count - 500)
        ELSE @row_min
        end
    AND
        RowNum < 
            Case sign(@row_count - 500 - @row_min)
            When -1 Then (@row_count)
            ELSE @row_min + 500
            end

--Note : Debugging purposes.
    select sign(@row_count - 500 - @row_min), (@row_count - 500 - @row_min), @row_count, @row_min
```