# SQL Row_Number() is very slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have one complex query in SQL which is taking long time, i.e. more than 1 min,  to produce the results due to `Row_Number()` in SQL. I am unable to find a better option in place of that. Below is my SQL query.

```
Declare  @AgreementNumber nvarchar(500)
     Declare   @SerialNo nvarchar(100)
     Declare    @EmailId nvarchar(1000)
     Declare    @CountryId nvarchar(10)
     Declare    @SaleType tinyint
     Declare    @CompanyName nvarchar(255)
     Declare    @PONo numeric(18,0)
     Declare   @Status tinyint
     Declare   @POCDeliveryType nvarchar(10)
     Declare   @FromDate datetime
     Declare   @ToDate datetime
     Declare    @CurrentPage numeric
     Declare    @PageSize numeric
     Declare   @FileId       numeric(18,0)
    Declare     @PurchaseOrg nvarchar(4)   

set @AgreementNumber =''
     set @SerialNo =''
     set @EmailId =''
     set @CountryId ='0014'
     set @SaleType=0
     set @CompanyName =''
     set @PONo= 0
     set @Status =0
     set @POCDeliveryType =''
     set @FromDate =''
     set @ToDate =''
     set @CurrentPage =1
     set @PageSize =100000
     set @FileId     =0
    set @PurchaseOrg ='' 



       ----For Paging---------------------------------------------------------------------
       Declare @TotalRecord numeric
       Declare @StartRow numeric
       Declare @EndRow numeric
       Set @StartRow=(@PageSize * (@CurrentPage-1)) + 1
       Set @EndRow=(@PageSize * (@CurrentPage)) 
       -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

       Select @TotalRecord=Count(*)
       From OrderHeader OH inner join OrderLine OL on OH.OrderID=OL.OrderId
       Where (OH.CountryId=@CountryId or ISNULL(@CountryId,'')='') and
       (OH.PurchaseOrg=@PurchaseOrg or ISNULL(@PurchaseOrg,'')='') and
              (SaleType=@SaleType or ISNULL(@SaleType,0)=0) and
              (CompanyName like '%'+ isnull(@CompanyName,'') + '%'or isnull(@CompanyName,'')='')and
              (PurchaseOrderNo = @PONo or isnull(@PONo,0)=0)and
              (OL.Status=@Status or ISNULL(@Status,0)=0) and
              (POCDeliveryPreference=@POCDeliveryType or ISNULL(@POCDeliveryType,'')='') and
              ((CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),OH.Created,112)>=CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),@FromDate,112))or (Isnull(@FromDate,'')=''))and
              (CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),OH.Created,112)<=CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),@ToDate,112)or (Isnull(@ToDate,'')='')) and
              (OL.SerialNumber like '%'+@SerialNo+'%' or ISNULL(@SerialNo,'') ='') and
              (OL.AgreementNumber like '%'+@AgreementNumber+'%' or ISNULL(@AgreementNumber,'') ='') and
              (OH.EmailAddress like '%'+@EmailId+'%' or ISNULL(@EmailId,'') ='') and
              (OH.FileId=@FileId or isnull(@FileId,0)=0)

       Select *, @TotalRecord as TotalRecord From
       (
              **Select ROW_NUMBER()  OVER 
              ( 
                     Order By OH.Created Desc
              )as Row**,OH.OrderID,ISNULL(CustomerId,'') as CustomerId,ISNULL(OH.CountryId,'') as CountryId,SaleType,HwPurchaseDate,ISNULL(AddressLine1,'') as
                     AddressLine1,ISNULL(AddressLine2,'') as AddressLine2,ISNULL(City,'') as City,ISNULL([State],'') as [State],ISNULL(Zip,'') as Zip,
                     ISNULL(County,'') as County,ISNULL(CompanyName,'') as CompanyName,ISNULL(EmailAddress,'') as EmailId,ISNULL(FirstName,'') as FirstName,
                     ISNULL(LastName,'') as LastName,ISNULL(PrimaryPhone,'') as Phone,ISNULL(PurchaseOrderNo,0) as POno,ISNULL(OL.[Status],0) as [Status],POCDeliveryPreference,
                     POCLanguage,CustPOReference,ISNULL(CurrencyCode,'') as CurrencyCode,TransactionId,ISNULL(OH.DeliveryStatus,0) as DeliveryStatus,
                     isnull(IPAddress,'') as IPAddress, ISNULL(InTouchSessionId,'') as InTouchSessionId, ISNULL(InTouchUserId,'') as InTouchUserId,
                     ISNULL(SourceSystem,0) as SourceSystem,SalesOrderDate,OH.Created,isnull(OL.SerialNumber,'') as SerialNumber,ISNULL(OL.AgreementNumber,'') as AgreementNumber,
                     ISNULL(OL.PurchaseOrderNoLineLevel,'') as PurchaseOrderNoLineLevel,ISNULL(OL.ProductName,'') as ProductName,ISNULL(OL.OrderQty,0) as OrderQty,
                     ISNULL(OL.ManufPartNo,'') as ManufPartNo,isnull(OL.VendorStatus,'') as VendorStatus, isnull(OL.StatusRemark, '') as StatusRemark

              From OrderHeader OH inner join OrderLine OL on OH.OrderID=OL.OrderId
              Where (OH.CountryId=@CountryId or ISNULL(@CountryId,'')='') and
              (OH.PurchaseOrg=@PurchaseOrg or ISNULL(@PurchaseOrg,'')='') and
              (SaleType=@SaleType or ISNULL(@SaleType,0)=0) and
              (CompanyName like '%'+ isnull(@CompanyName,'') + '%'or isnull(@CompanyName,'')='')and
              (PurchaseOrderNo = @PONo or isnull(@PONo,0)=0)and
              (OL.Status=@Status or ISNULL(@Status,0)=0) and
              (POCDeliveryPreference=@POCDeliveryType or ISNULL(@POCDeliveryType,'')='') and
              ((CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),OH.Created,112)>=CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),@FromDate,112))or (Isnull(@FromDate,'')=''))and
              (CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),OH.Created,112)<=CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),@ToDate,112)or (Isnull(@ToDate,'')='')) and
              (OL.SerialNumber like '%'+@SerialNo+'%' or ISNULL(@SerialNo,'') ='') and
              (OL.AgreementNumber like '%'+@AgreementNumber+'%' or ISNULL(@AgreementNumber,'') ='') and
              (OH.EmailAddress like '%'+@EmailId+'%' or ISNULL(@EmailId,'') ='') and
              (OH.FileId=@FileId or isnull(@FileId,0)=0)
       )
       as RowResults
       Where Row between @StartRow AND  @EndRow
```

I have highlighted that part which is taking so long time.

Comment: So it's fast if you remove the `ROW_NUMBER`? Create an index  `Created DESC`

Comment: How big are the tables? have you profiled the query? Is there an index on OH.Created.

Comment: You may consider not running a large duplicated select each time just to fetch total rows: [Return total records from SQL Server when using ROW_NUMBER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790965/return-total-records-from-sql-server-when-using-row-number)

Comment: btw which sql server version you are using.
and indexes definition plz

Answer (score 1):

```
OH.CountryId = @CountryId or ISNULL(@CountryId, '') = '')
```

Generally these sorts of things should be avoided. It prevents SQL Server from performing an index seek and instead performs an index scan. Can you use dynamic SQL instead and include in the `where OH.CountryId = @CountryId` only when its specified?

Comment: Same, if not more so for functions on date columns and like %xxx%. This query is set up to fail from the outset. Truly horrible!

Comment: Have you rewritten the query? Please append the updated query to your question as we can't see what "This" is.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
((CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),OH.Created,112)>=CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),@FromDate,112))

(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),OH.Created,112)<=CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),@ToDate,112)
```

by `Cast(OH.Created as date)>=Cast(@FromDate as date)
Cast(OH.Created as date)<=Cast(@FromDate as date)`

the convert creating a plan that is not the best.

Comment: or even better: OH.Created >= Cast(@FromDate as date) and
OH.Created < Cast(dateadd(d, 1, @FromDate) as date)

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of issue in query itself

(1) Using same query twice

(2) trying to catch all query(inefficiently ) that can produce horrible plan

(3) Using predicate like OH.EmailAddress like '%'+@EmailId+'%'

(4) inefficient paging

```
Declare  @AgreementNumber nvarchar(500)
     Declare   @SerialNo nvarchar(100)
     Declare    @EmailId nvarchar(1000)
     Declare    @CountryId nvarchar(10)
     Declare    @SaleType tinyint
     Declare    @CompanyName nvarchar(255)
     Declare    @PONo numeric(18,0)
     Declare   @Status tinyint
     Declare   @POCDeliveryType nvarchar(10)
     Declare   @FromDate datetime
     Declare   @ToDate datetime
     Declare    @CurrentPage numeric
     Declare    @PageSize numeric
     Declare   @FileId       numeric(18,0)
    Declare     @PurchaseOrg nvarchar(4)   

set @AgreementNumber =''
     set @SerialNo =''
     set @EmailId =''
     set @CountryId ='0014'
     set @SaleType=0
     set @CompanyName =''
     set @PONo= 0
     set @Status =0
     set @POCDeliveryType =''
     set @FromDate =''
     set @ToDate =''
     set @CurrentPage =1
     set @PageSize =100000
     set @FileId     =0
    set @PurchaseOrg ='' 



       ----For Paging---------------------------------------------------------------------
       Declare @TotalRecord numeric
       Declare @StartRow numeric
       Declare @EndRow numeric
       Set @StartRow=(@PageSize * (@CurrentPage-1)) + 1
       Set @EndRow=(@PageSize * (@CurrentPage)) 
       -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

       --Select @TotalRecord=Count(*)
       --From OrderHeader OH inner join OrderLine OL on OH.OrderID=OL.OrderId
       --Where (OH.CountryId=@CountryId or ISNULL(@CountryId,'')='') and
       --(OH.PurchaseOrg=@PurchaseOrg or ISNULL(@PurchaseOrg,'')='') and
       --       (SaleType=@SaleType or ISNULL(@SaleType,0)=0) and
       --       (CompanyName like '%'+ isnull(@CompanyName,'') + '%'or isnull(@CompanyName,'')='')and
       --       (PurchaseOrderNo = @PONo or isnull(@PONo,0)=0)and
       --       (OL.Status=@Status or ISNULL(@Status,0)=0) and
       --       (POCDeliveryPreference=@POCDeliveryType or ISNULL(@POCDeliveryType,'')='') and
       --       ((CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),OH.Created,112)>=CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),@FromDate,112))or (Isnull(@FromDate,'')=''))and
       --       (CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),OH.Created,112)<=CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),@ToDate,112)or (Isnull(@ToDate,'')='')) and
       --       (OL.SerialNumber like '%'+@SerialNo+'%' or ISNULL(@SerialNo,'') ='') and
       --       (OL.AgreementNumber like '%'+@AgreementNumber+'%' or ISNULL(@AgreementNumber,'') ='') and
       --       (OH.EmailAddress like '%'+@EmailId+'%' or ISNULL(@EmailId,'') ='') and
       --       (OH.FileId=@FileId or isnull(@FileId,0)=0)





       With RowResults as

      (

        Select ROW_NUMBER()  OVER 
              ( 
                     Order By OH.Created Desc
              )as Row ,OH.OrderID,ISNULL(CustomerId,'') as CustomerId,ISNULL(OH.CountryId,'') as CountryId,SaleType,HwPurchaseDate,ISNULL(AddressLine1,'') as
                     AddressLine1,ISNULL(AddressLine2,'') as AddressLine2,ISNULL(City,'') as City,ISNULL([State],'') as [State],ISNULL(Zip,'') as Zip,
                     ISNULL(County,'') as County,ISNULL(CompanyName,'') as CompanyName,ISNULL(EmailAddress,'') as EmailId,ISNULL(FirstName,'') as FirstName,
                     ISNULL(LastName,'') as LastName,ISNULL(PrimaryPhone,'') as Phone,ISNULL(PurchaseOrderNo,0) as POno,ISNULL(OL.[Status],0) as [Status],POCDeliveryPreference,
                     POCLanguage,CustPOReference,ISNULL(CurrencyCode,'') as CurrencyCode,TransactionId,ISNULL(OH.DeliveryStatus,0) as DeliveryStatus,
                     isnull(IPAddress,'') as IPAddress, ISNULL(InTouchSessionId,'') as InTouchSessionId, ISNULL(InTouchUserId,'') as InTouchUserId,
                     ISNULL(SourceSystem,0) as SourceSystem,SalesOrderDate,OH.Created,isnull(OL.SerialNumber,'') as SerialNumber,ISNULL(OL.AgreementNumber,'') as AgreementNumber,
                     ISNULL(OL.PurchaseOrderNoLineLevel,'') as PurchaseOrderNoLineLevel,ISNULL(OL.ProductName,'') as ProductName,ISNULL(OL.OrderQty,0) as OrderQty,
                     ISNULL(OL.ManufPartNo,'') as ManufPartNo,isnull(OL.VendorStatus,'') as VendorStatus, isnull(OL.StatusRemark, '') as StatusRemark

              From OrderHeader OH inner join OrderLine OL on OH.OrderID=OL.OrderId
              Where (OH.CountryId=@CountryId or ISNULL(@CountryId,'')='') and
              (OH.PurchaseOrg=@PurchaseOrg or ISNULL(@PurchaseOrg,'')='') and
              (SaleType=@SaleType or ISNULL(@SaleType,0)=0) and
              (CompanyName like '%'+ isnull(@CompanyName,'') + '%'or isnull(@CompanyName,'')='')and
              (PurchaseOrderNo = @PONo or isnull(@PONo,0)=0)and
              (OL.Status=@Status or ISNULL(@Status,0)=0) and
              (POCDeliveryPreference=@POCDeliveryType or ISNULL(@POCDeliveryType,'')='') and
              ((CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),OH.Created,112)>=CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),@FromDate,112))or (Isnull(@FromDate,'')=''))and
              (CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),OH.Created,112)<=CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),@ToDate,112)or (Isnull(@ToDate,'')='')) and
              (OL.SerialNumber like '%'+@SerialNo+'%' or ISNULL(@SerialNo,'') ='') and
              (OL.AgreementNumber like '%'+@AgreementNumber+'%' or ISNULL(@AgreementNumber,'') ='') and
              (OH.EmailAddress like '%'+@EmailId+'%' or ISNULL(@EmailId,'') ='') and
              (OH.FileId=@FileId or isnull(@FileId,0)=0)
       )


Select max (Row) , * FRom      RowResults
 Where Row between @StartRow AND  @EndRow
 option (recompile)
 -- quick fix only 



-- --if using SQL SERVER 2012
--  OFFSET @StartRow ROWS
--FETCH NEXT @EndRow -@StartRow  ROWS ONLY





   --if  ans still not gaining performance we wold like to see actual exection plan
```

--(1) Using same query twice  DONE

--(2) trying to catch all query(inefficiently ) that can produce horrible plan   DONE by option recompile (still you need to understand this use dynamic query if you are not exposed to sql injection)

--(3) Using predicate like OH.EmailAddress like '%'+@EmailId+'%' -- you need to adress this

--(4) inefficient paging -- fetch next is quite fast that row_num .